# Change value or create it if it does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I want to modify a certan value from build.prop file which looks like this

```
ro.product.brand=Asus
ro.product.name=lineage_Z00T
ro.product.device=Z00T
```

Whats the best way to change ro.product.brand value from "Asus" to "Samsung". And if this value does not exist then create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search if the value is present :

```
grep 'ro.product.brand=' build.prop
```

Modify it :

```
sed -E 's/(ro.product.brand=).*/\1Samsung/' build.prop
```

Create it :

```
echo 'ro.product.brand=Samsung' >> build.prop
```

Full script :

```
if grep 'ro.product.brand=' build.prop; then
  sed -E 's/(ro.product.brand=).*/\1Samsung/' build.prop
else
  echo 'ro.product.brand=Samsung' >> build.prop
fi
```

Note that this will change the value to Samsung whether its current value is Asus or anything else, you can change that by restricting the `grep` to match only the line with the expected value.

Note that you can greatly simplify the process by deleting the line if present and creating it with its target value unconditionally :

```
sed '/ro.product.brand=/d' build.prop
echo 'ro.product.brand=Samsung' >> build.prop
```